# iPhone panel control

Tags: iphone, controls

In my iPad application there are many buttons (around 50), and I want to make a group box which contain buttons arranged by category.

I am looking for something like a C# or .NET [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx)/[Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is no Group Box / Panel Box in iPhone.

You need to manage by your self.

Use the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to put all the button in on category.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

It may be worthwhile to look into UIPopoverController views.  These are the little popup views that appear when you click stuff.  YOu could easily break your menu system into smaller parts with these.

Comment: Those aren't available on the iPhone and iPod touch, only the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You may draw a group panel by making two views. make a view of frame say 20,20,280,199 and then another one with frame 21,21,278,197. now put the 2nd view on the last one and change the color of last to some dark than later one. enjoy :)

remember that the should be in same hierarchy. that no one should be parent or child of any of these.